# Does extending a parent class in PHP require the file with the class being included?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, require

Should I include/require_once the parent class that  I am extending in PHP?

for example I have  a class called Shapes

```
class Shapes {

}
```

And then I created a subclass called

```
require_once('shapes.php');

class Circle extends Shapes {

}
```

Should I require the parent class when I am extending? or should just use extends the subclass to itss parent class even though they are in the same folder?

Comment: have you looked at auto loading? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to do *something* in order to let PHP see your base class definition before it can process the child class, otherwise a fatal error will occur.

This something can be either a manual `require_once` of the base class file, or [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) (there are other options for autoloading, but [`spl_autoload_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) is the one you should use).

Which approach to use depends on the scope: when coding a small test project setting up autoloading is probably overkill. But as the code base gets larger and larger, autoloading becomes more attractive because:

- it can hide complex source file resolution logic (e.g. if you have a configurable directory for the base classes; there are more advanced scenarios as well)
- it can be configured incrementally: you can use multiple autoloaders that run as a chain, and each independent module of the application can register its independent autoloader that coexists peacefully with all the others

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to include it if that class is not declared in the same file.

Also there was a feature called [Autoloading Classes](http://prototype.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) with which you can create a function like this one:

```
function __autoload($class){
    require_once('classes/' . $class . '.php');
}
```

And it will automatically include classes which are not found in the existing scope

Also you can read about this feature too: [autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use composer to simplify the process.

Make `composer.json` like this

```
{
...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
...
}
```

Get composer from https://getcomposer.org/ and run `composer install`.
You should load composer's autoload script once like

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

If you have PHP less than 5.3.0 then replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)`.

And put your files to `src` folder. For example if you have the class `Acme\Utils\FooBar` then it should be in `src/Acme/Utils/FooBar.php`.